# How to add Icon to Pyinstaller in Windows 10

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I modified the spec file to include the icon but every time I generate the exe, the system is throwing this error:

```
2105 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 40 bytes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 269, in UpdateResource
    handle, type, name, language, lp_data, len(lp_data))
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_resource.py", line 134, in _UpdateResource
    function_name='UpdateResource')
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 81, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I tried generating the exe file directly from pyinstaller using `--onefile` and also from .spec file.

block_cipher = None

Add the ico to exe file

Comment: exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='sample',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True, icon='logo.ico')

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from os import path 
script_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(SPEC))
exe = EXE(pyz,
         a.scripts,
         a.binaries,
         a.zipfiles,
         a.datas,
         x, y,
         name='super_program',
         debug=False,
         strip=False,
         upx=True,
         runtime_tmpdir=None,
         console=True,
         icon=os.path.join(script_dir, 'icon.ico'))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options):

> -i , --icon       FILE.ico: apply that icon to a Windows
>   executable. FILE.exe,ID, extract the icon with ID from an exe.
>   FILE.icns: apply the icon to the .app bundle on Mac OS X

So you need to use:

`pyinstaller -F --icon "youricon.ico" "yourscript.py"`